# Customise UINavigationBar to make it invisible, but keep buttons visible

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I know that iOS 5 allows for UINavigationBar customisation, but I'm not sure it does what I need. I want to remove the bar entirely, or at least make it invisible, but keep the buttons (backButton, rightBarButton, etc) and replace them with my own images. I could implement actual buttons, but keeping the navBar is far more convenient as I want to use its behaviour. Is this possible? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the navBar to hidden and handle all of the navigation yourself. The navigation controller is still there, but navigation is overridden with your custom buttons.

Comment: Perhaps this is the simplest solution.

Comment: We do this at work all the time. It forces you to build your own navbar/buttons, but you can do whatever you want with it and just push/pop the views on and off as needed. Building a nice UI... that is up to you. ;)

Comment: An alternative solution that keeps the buttons visible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969248/how-to-draw-a-transparent-uitoolbar-or-uinavigationbar-in-ios7