# How to make completely transparent navigation bar in iOS 7

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, transparency, translucency

I want the UINavigationBar in my app to be completely transparent and flush with the viewcontroller directly under it. However, the only code I could find makes it translucent but not transparent. I know this can be done in iOS 7 because it is used in the notes app. My question is, what is the code they used to do it?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969248/how-to-draw-a-transparent-uitoolbar-or-uinavigationbar-in-ios7)

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Also, as suggested by Josh in the comments, to put the bar back to default:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil
                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: When I do it (in a UIViewController), I have to change the code to say `self.navigationController.navigationBar` and all it does is change the bar to black.

Comment: That code should be fine. It may just be the background colour, try adding self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: Also make sure you dont have `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

Comment: Is there a way to reverse this?

Comment: @Zorayr [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; will put the bar back to default.

Comment: And if you need to change the color of the text once you've made your nav bar transparent, add `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Comment: Works also on iOS 6.1

Comment: This causes the navigationBar to show a black image for a second while navigation back it to. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Is there any way to toggle navigation bar's transparency animated using this method?

Comment: I implement this on scrollViewDidScroll and there's a jump. How to fix?

Comment: Thanks Shahid, I have edited the answer to include reversing the effect.

Comment: I used the accepted answer, the nav bar became transparent but the page scroll causes a jump on uipagecontroller, any suggestions on how that can be fixed?

Comment: Why my navigation color changed to black after this code applies? :(

Answer (score 79):

**For Swift3 and Swift4**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

**For Swift2.2**

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

***For Objective-C***

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks this is an easy way to set the navigation bar to totally transparent

Answer (score 39):

Self contained solution as an Objective-C Category:

**UINavigationController+TransparentNavigationController.h**

```
@interface UINavigationController (TransparentNavigationController)
- (void)presentTransparentNavigationBar;
- (void)hideTransparentNavigationBar;
@end
```

**UINavigationController+TransparentNavigationController.m**

```
#import "UINavigationController+TransparentNavigationController.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (TransparentNavigationController)

- (void)presentTransparentNavigationBar
{
  [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [self.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
  [self.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
  [self setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)hideTransparentNavigationBar
{
  [self setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
  [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UINavigationBar appearance] backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [self.navigationBar setTranslucent:[[UINavigationBar appearance] isTranslucent]];
  [self.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UINavigationBar appearance] shadowImage]];
}

@end
```

Now, you can import the category in your `UIViewController` and call the methods on your navigation controller - for example:

```
#import "UINavigationController+TransparentNavigationController.h"

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self.navigationController presentTransparentNavigationBar];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [self.navigationController hideTransparentNavigationBar];
}
```

And a similar solution in **Swift**:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UINavigationController {

  public func presentTransparentNavigationBar() {
    navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default)
    navigationBar.translucent = true
    navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:true)
  }

  public func hideTransparentNavigationBar() {
    setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated:false)
    navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundImageForBarMetrics(UIBarMetrics.Default), forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default)
    navigationBar.translucent = UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent
    navigationBar.shadowImage = UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i show it again (for example if ill want to make it transparent only in 1 view in an NavigationController?) - can i reset it to my default values?

Comment: `hideTransparentNavigationBar()` should reset it back.

Comment: Calling present/hide methods in viewWillAppear/disappear cause a bad transition animation between the two differents navigation bar! You can see it very well by doing the swipe gesture (from left to right) in the pushedViewController

Comment: Try calling it in `viewDidHide` of the parent view controller.

Comment: Black background is shown on iOS 11 when using LargeTitle when hiding transparent navbar

Answer (score 15):

Alan forgot one line

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

So I have:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 5):

@Zorayr's great answer revised to Swift 3 :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UINavigationController {

    public func presentTransparentNavigationBar() {
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:.default)
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:true)
    }

    public func hideTransparentNavigationBar() {
        setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated:false)
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundImage(for: UIBarMetrics.default), for:.default)
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2 and iOS 12**

It turns out all you really need is the code below. It works perfectly when you put it into `viewDidLoad()`.

```
// removes line at bottom of navigation bar
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

// makes navigation bar completely transparent
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Answer (score -3):

Use [UINavigationBar+Addition](https://github.com/samwize/UINavigationBar-Addition) pod, then simply call:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
[navigationBar makeTransparent];
```

Answer (score -4):

[(UIView*)[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setAlpha:0.0f];

That one line seemed to work perfectly for me