# Xamarin iOS Navigation Bar 100% Transparency

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, xamarin

i´m developing an iOS-Application with VisualStudio/Xamarin. I have to set the transparency on the navigationbar to 100%. But let me explain the whole thing:

On the first view the navigationbar have a background image set by this code:

```
var navigationImage = UIImage.FromFile("gradient.jpg");
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(navigationImage, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

The first view got several tablecell items, if clicked, a detail view shows up.
On that detail view the navigationbar should be completely transparent! Only the back button and a title should be leftover.

I tried everything from `translucent = yes` to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082963/how-to-make-completely-transparent-navigation-bar-in-ios-7) which i also found here on stackoverflow.

I also tried to set a color to the first navigationbar and then change it on the next view to another color which works, but if i get back to the firstview the navigationbar color stays the same, even if i override the `ViewWillAppear`-method from the first view where the `BarTintColor` is set.

Thanks for your help!

greetings

Answer (score 2):

Well, for what it's worth, I actually followed your solution link and translated it to Xamarin. If I put the following code in ViewDidLoad on my VC, the Navigation Bar is completely transparant ;)

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage (new UIImage (), UIBarMetrics.Default);
this.NavigationController.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage ();
```