# Transparent UINavigationBar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to make my `UINavigationBar` in `UINavigationController` transparent. I created a subclass of `UINavigationController` and liked it to a scene in my storyboard file. Here's a piece of my subclass:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let size = self.navigationBar.frame.size
    self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(UIColor.blackColor(), size: size, alpha: 0.2), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, alpha: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let fillRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(currentContext, color.CGColor)
    CGContextSetAlpha(currentContext, alpha)
    CGContextFillRect(currentContext, fillRect)
    let retval: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return retval
}
```

When I run my application a have a navigation bar transparent, but status bar is just black.

For example if I do such thing on `UITabBar` - it works.

Answer (score 120):

Hope it help you

**Swift 2:**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

**Swift 4.2** to **Swift 5.1**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Or If you want to sublcass the navigation controller then refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611375/3202193).

---

Change the status bar style via :

In your Info.plist you need to define *View controller-based status bar appearance* to any value.

[image]

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

If you want to hide the status bar:

```
UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
```

Getting this output by light content and by transparent navigation. I have view background is gray. you can see the transparency.

[image]

iPhone XR - Swift 4.2 - Large Titles (Test Screenshot)

[image: Large Titles - Swift - iPhone XR]

Comment: What do you mean by transparent then ? @NikitaZernov Transparent = clear color. you can see only titles and button.

Comment: He want to make his status bar transparent.

Comment: @NikitaZernov see the updated answer. I could not understand actual issue. I have added code for status bar

Comment: Also make sure ViewController's "Under Top Bar" feature is checked

Comment: @NikitaZernov add opacity from color to 50%

Comment: Note that you should also add a `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear` line in order to make the navigation bar transparent.

Comment: Not working properly with iOS 11 `prefersLargeTitles` set to true.

Comment: @3000 Tested in iOS 12.1 - Swift 4.2 - iPhone XR Working Fine.

Comment: @Tulleb Working fine in iOS 12. Please check screenshot with large titles. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @AshishKakkad: I'm investigating, maybe this is something related to other things, eg. extended top edges, etc.

Comment: Doesn't work for me... I don't know what I missed...

Answer (score 32):

If you're using Swift 2.0 uses the code block below:

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

For Swift 3.0 use:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3.0.1 with Xcode 8.1

In your `UINavigationController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Xcode 8.x : Swift 3: Extension for the same
Write once use throughout

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func transparentNavigationBar() {
        self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.isTranslucent = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Create an extension of `UINavigationController` and present or hide transparent navigation bar.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    public func presentTransparentNavigationBar() {
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:true)
    }

    public func hideTransparentNavigationBar() {
        setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated:false)
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundImage(for: UIBarMetrics.default), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct, calling `setNavigationBarHidden` will also hide back button and navigation item, that's not what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

I tried all methods above and still got white space instead of content that supposed to be rendered through. If you want to draw regular subview (Google map f.e.), not UIScrollView content through navigation bar, then you need to set subview's frame in `viewDidAppear`.
So step 1:

```
existingNavigationBar.setBackgroundImage(transparentImageFromAssets, for: .default)
existingNavigationBar.shadowImage = transparentImageFromAssets
existingNavigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

step 2:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
      self.mapView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
  }
```

This worked for me.