# trying to make nav bar clear, and it's black

Tags: ios, swift

I am inside a UINavigationController. The UINavigationController has 3 view controllers. The first 2 are tableViewControllers, the last one is a regular view controller, with a PageViewController embedded.

I am using the following code in the third view controller in the stack to make the UINavigationBar clear:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

I put this code in the **third** view controller in the stack. That is the view controller with a UIPageViewController embedded. But the nav bar is black. However, when I pop the third controller off the stack and go back to the second, a UITableViewController, the navigation bar there is clear.

I have looked at numerous other questions, here: [How to make completely transparent navigation bar in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082963/how-to-make-completely-transparent-navigation-bar-in-ios-7) and here: [Transparent UINavigationBar in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545663/transparent-uinavigationbar-in-swift) but nothing works.

what am I doing wrong? the 2 lines of code above are the only ones I'm using, but I have also tried the suggestions in the links above, and nothing works. Here is a photo of the black nav bar:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the where in the life cycle of the view controller you are trying to manipulate the navigationBar, and how you are presenting the third view controller?  It sounds like your code is working (the bar when you pop the 3rd VC off the stack is transparent) but it is happening too late.  Have you tried putting the navigationBar code where the 3rd VC is being presented?

Comment: you can just set `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clearColor()` instead of setting an image to it

Comment: I have tried it in 1) the viewDidLoad, 2) viewWilAppear, and 3) prepareForSegue in 2nd view controller. As I said, when I go back, the navigation bar in the 2nd VC is clear. But when I got back to the first one, it is black again. Here is a 45 sec youtube video showing the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubNBMmt2oLU

Comment: @iamalizade I tried that and it did not affect anything

Comment: @joey hmm, it should work. May be you overwrite it elsewhere?

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me, when I was struggling with the same problem, was to subclass the NavigationController, and use this in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

another reason might be that your ViewController doesn't extended under your `UINavigationBar`, and thats why you see the black part, try setting this in the `viewDidLoad` of your `ViewContorller`

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeTop;
```