# iOS 11 - Adding Background image to Navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a view controller with Large Titles and I want to add a background image to it so it takes up the whole navigation bar.
Does anyone know the best way to do this. I've search all over the internet but yet to find any good examples.
Thank you

## Goal is to look like this view from starbucks app.

[image: Click this to see an example of how I want it to look]

Comment: You can create transparent navigation bar to display this kind of content https://stackoverflow.com/a/30545730/3202193

Comment: go with the parallax ..https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader

Comment: I think the best way is that you can custom your own navigation bar instead of use default navigation bar

Comment: I really want it to collapse too. Do you guys think the parallax method is best?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the image. I think the best way is to add an image view at top. Then on that image view place two buttons with appropriate constraints. Then underneath that image view, add the tableview. Then in the table view cell, at first index you can add the textview, if it is a large text and underneath cells will cover all the things your require with labels in the left and the > image in the right which will lead to a different screen.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem just like this and I didn't find any solution over the internet neither. But I do have a simple work around that might be helpful.

What I did is setting the image as navigation bar's background and also add the image to the view in the VC. Make sure the navigation bar has no shadow and its `translucent` property is set to `NO`.