# how to adjust the position of the UINavigationBar in swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, view, uinavigationbar

I would like to reposition the UINavigationBar. So I used the code to give a new value, but it hasn't changed.

```swift
@IBOutlet var headerBar: UINavigationBar!
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if screenHeight > 667 {
            headerBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 54, width: headerBar.frame.width, height: headerBar.frame.height))
        } else {
            headerBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: headerBar.frame.width, height: headerBar.frame.height))
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

### I ran on the main thread but there was no change.

```swift
@IBOutlet var headerBar: UINavigationBar!
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.screenHeight > 667 {
                self.headerBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 54, width: self.headerBar.frame.width, height: self.headerBar.frame.height))
            } else {
                self.headerBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: self.headerBar.frame.width, height: self.headerBar.frame.height))
            }
        }
    }
```

### Headerbar Area Viewed from Main Storyboard

**NOTE: This header bar is obscured by the navigation controller bar in the picture. But I'm hiding the navigation controller bar in the code.**
[image]

Comment: call your condition in main thread. or else call in
 viewDidAppear

Comment: it's already in main thread. (in `viewDidLoad:` method)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I ran on the main thread but there was no change.

Comment: @Mahendra Why isn't it changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
             let bounds = self.headerBar.bounds
           self.headerBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.screenHeight > 667 ? 54 : 40, width:bounds.width, height: bounds.height )

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: @iosbegindevel - yes sure

Comment: I'd like to make the header bar transparent. But it doesn't work. headerBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0)

Comment: @iosbegindevel - see this for help : [Transparent UINavigationBar in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545663/transparent-uinavigationbar-in-swift/30545730)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm admiring your