# iOS after set edgesForExtendedLayout to UIRectEdgeNone, set Transparent navigationbar not work

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

As the title said, after I use `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`,
I want to set the navigation bar to transparent. I use the code like this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```

But it doesn't work. The navigation bar is shown black. How should I make the navigation bar transparent?

[image: My IOS page screenshot]

Comment: You're setting a solid background image for the navigation bar, so why would you think it would be transparent afterwards? Also, this functionality is different on iOS7 and iOS8, as on iOS8 transparent navigation bars are default.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen it is not solid background image,  i use the code in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082963/how-to-make-completely-transparent-navigation-bar-in-ios-7), if i comment `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` , that will be  completely transparent. but the view will under navigation bar.

Comment: You really need to specify which version of iOS you're using. What you just said is not true for iOS8.