# make transparent navigation bar and transparent tab bar in ios 7.

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7

how to create a transparent tab bar and navigation bar in ios 7 ? i tried setting

```
[[UITabBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

but then a translucent tab bar appears. then i tried setting the translucency property of tab bar to NO

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

also the tab button is always highlighted in blue color. Even though i put different color images .
has anyone had similar experiences ? observed only in ios7

Comment: Please re-word question. It sounds like you are dismissing the results you were looking for. But whatever your meaning, you might try doing a search for iOS 7 bar color.

Comment: This question has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18969325/1047520

Answer (score 3):

By default the selected tab button item has highlighted blue color and unselected has gray color. This behavior is a independent of tool bar item image color.

Example to change the selection color for tab Bar item

```
self.tabController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: tanks.. it did change the tab item color. Any help on changing the tab bar and navigation bar color transparent?

Comment: Try this self.tabController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];. Hopefully it will solve your problem

Comment: try to play with alpha value.  self.tabController.tabBar.alpha = 0.5f;