# How to make navigation bar transparent in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, transparent

Is there a way to make the bar of a navigation controller totally transparent?

What i've tried:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setAlpha:0.0];
```

but the bar's appearance does not change, and stays white translucent.
I'm trying to get visible the bar items, but not the bar itself. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: This is answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969248/how-to-draw-a-transparent-uitoolbar-or-uinavigationbar-in-ios7

Answer (score 68):

If anybody is wondering how to achieve this in iOS 7, here's a solution (iOS 6 compatible too)

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Setting translucent to YES on the navigation bar does the trick, due to a behaviour discussed in the UINavigationBar documentation. I'll report here the relevant fragment:

If you set this property to YES on a navigation bar with an opaque custom background image, the navigation bar will apply a system opacity less than 1.0 to the image.

Reference from: [Make UINavigationBar transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/make-uinavigationbar-transparent)

Comment: I tried this, it works but now the back button is not visible any solution for that.

Comment: @nuteron Try with this may be it will help you:
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

Comment: @Pradhyumansinh Thank you for your solution. After setting bar to translucent, I want to revert to default background. What should I do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298375/revert-navigation-bars-background-image-to-default

Answer (score 22):

You can make Navigation Bar Transparent with following code

---

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[self.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Comment: Can we set the alpha of the navigation bar if we do like this?

Comment: ya definitely, you can do this by `[self.navigationBar setAlpha:YourValue];`

Comment: @HareshGhatala Thank you for your solution. After setting bar to translucent, I want to revert to default background. What should I do? stackoverflow.com/questions/24298375/… –  nimingzhe2008 5 mins ago   edit