# Revert navigation bar's background image to default

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

At first, I set navigation bar's background to translucent.

```
    barImage=[[self.navigationController.navigationBar backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault] copy];//barImage is a UIImage point     
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                             forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```

It works well.
Now I need to revert navigation bar's background image to default.

```
- (void)dealloc
{

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:barImage
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil;

}
```

This doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still stuck on this, but here's the code to reverse the effect. I borrowed a navigation controller, and copied everything over to the original navigation controller.

```
    UINavigationController *tempNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[[UIViewController alloc]init]];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[tempNavigationController.navigationBar backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [tempNavigationController.navigationBar shadowImage];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = tempNavigationController.view.backgroundColor;

    tempNavigationController = nil;
```