# Transclucent navigation bar moving section header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

I am just a simple guy struggling to get a translucent navigation bar.
I have tried to set it in appDelegate and in the spesific ViewController.
What i end up with is this:
Does anyone know why the section header in white is moved down? The navigation bar is not even translucent when i scroll and i can´t set a color to it. (i can set color when translucent = false)
I have tried to set it to translucent and opaque and inferred in storyboard.(not working)

Update:

```
let colorImage = imageFromColor(UIColor(red:0.22, green:0.23, blue:0.29, alpha:0.5), frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 340, 64))
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = colorImage
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

The colorImage is a image i make with a rgb-uicolor. The outcome is this: [navigation bar 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NLiQ.png)

It is transclucent between the section header, but the top bar is not!

[UPDATE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAguQ.png)

Comment: A quick search in SO would give you a lot of results on this topic. Take a look at this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319439/how-to-make-navigation-bar-transparent-in-ios-7

Comment: Ty for reply. I have already tried that in my viewController and appDelegate, but the result is the same as in the picture!

Comment: Please provide the code, so that it would be easier to debug.

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = colorImage
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
    }

Comment: Are you trying to display a custom `shadowImage` for your `navigationBar` or is it only because it was mentioned in the code? Check after commenting out that line of code

Comment: Yes, it was to make it a gray color. It is still the same, just without gray-color.  I think I have a case of "Double navigation bars". Maybe I am doing something wrong in the storyboard with the connection between my tabBar controller and the navigation controllers

Comment: To understand your requirement clearly, are you trying to achieve something like the top section in this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQzd3.png)

Comment: That is what I want!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set a translucent background for `navigationBar` across your application, you can use the following code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of your `AppDelegate`

```
let colorImage = getImageWithColor(UIColor(red:0.22, green:0.23, blue:0.29, alpha:0.5), size: CGSizeMake(360, 64))
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(colorImage, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

> Result Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If i didn´t have two navigationbars on top of each other this would have been perfect!

Comment: Why do you have two navigationBars? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: My problem is that I have two, and have no idea why. I only want one!